# java security exception: sealing violation while trying to connect to database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, java

I am facing an issue with oracle db connection after changing java runtime to 1.6.
Earlier our application used 1.5 java runtime and now we are migrating 1.6. Application is throwing the following exception while trying to connect to oracle 10g db:

> failed. Error: Verify operation
>   failed. Errors: [ORACLE-10002: Error
>   received from connection to Oracle
>   database +ASM:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: sealing
>   violation: package oracle.jdbc is
>   sealed]

It is working properly if I use jre 1.5 instead of 1.6 jre.
It is working fine with oracle 11g database and jre 1.6 combination.
Have any of you faced similar issues? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would speculate that its an issue with the oracle drivers. We experienced something similar when going from java 1.4 to 1.6, though it was a different error. Have you tried downgrading your [JDBC drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) to the 10g version?

Comment: suggest copying the ojdbc14.jar from your 10g home directory to make sure you are using that one.

Comment: right now we are using ojdbc5 jar. I shall replace it with ojdbc14 jar and try once.