# Oracle DB connection error: package is sealed

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

While trying to execute a sql query i got an exception:

> java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package oracle.jdbc.driver is sealed

Looks lite there is conflict between jdbc drivers. Has anyone faced such problem? Thanks.

Comment: have you googling it? http://www.appshippo.com/how-stuffs-28/sealing-violation-package-oracle-jdbc-driver-sealed-resolved-coldfusion-error-5582/ for example

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922369/java-security-exception-sealing-violation-while-trying-to-connect-to-database

Comment: Please edit your post to include the Java code.

Comment: The code is actually doesn't matter because it wasn't changed. Error is happened after migrating to GlassFish.

Comment: The solution was found: there was a ojdbc library duplication (at project's lib folder and at glassfish's lib/ext folder).