# oracle jdbc driver not working as i wanted

Tags: oracle, driver, ojdbc

I'm a bit confused with oracle jdbc.

i use ojdbc16

by following those step i get :

1) adding ojdbc.jar to my build path
  -> everything work in local ( connexion, request etc..)

2) trying to test my webApp with jetty
    `sealing violation: package oracle.jdbc is sealed`
I dont see where the drivers can be load appart from ojdbc.jar :/ maybe it come from a copy/paste from Nexus ? so i remove the dependencies "ojdbc" from the pom.xml.

3) trying to test my webApp with jetty. It's now working (huh)
if i do eclipse:eclipse (Update of my classpath) this is not working anymore.

4) when i run my Junit Test, it fail because oracle driver seems to be unfindable.

I'm confused, how can step 3 work. And how can step 4 doesn't work as step 3 work ? and how can i fix my probleme with ojdbc ?
Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [java security exception: sealing violation while trying to connect to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922369/java-security-exception-sealing-violation-while-trying-to-connect-to-database)

Comment: it's not working with neither ojdbc14, ojdbc16, ojdbc5. Some office colleague use ojdbc14 without any problem (we use nexus as repository manager, so it's the same .jar).

Comment: The following link indicates that issue might be multiple copies of the jar on your classpath: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4704115

Comment: It's not. there is only one : 
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/oracle/ojdbc14/10.2.0.3.0/ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar"/>

Answer (score -1):

Summary: If you find the class at compile time but not at runtime, this might help: Try copying the ojdbcXX.jar file you use to the java folder structure...

Details:

I've been wrestling with this for two days - and reading lots of stackoverflow answers, many helped my understanding of related things :-).  Just now I came across a solution that worked for me.

I am using: Windows 7 64-bit; Eclipse Kepler; Oracle 12.1; JDK1.7; ojdbc7.jar.  My classpath included the folder with ojdbc7.jar. My imports in the code were fine, and the code itself found the class at compile time.  The library settings in my Eclipse project also included the folder with the ojdbc7.jar files.  My Java Build Path | Order and Export tab had everything ticked, including the ojdbc7.jar (thanks StackOverflow for that one).

The last missing piece: I needed to copy the ojdbc7.jar file from the oracle folder structure to the Java folder structure, so it could find it at runtime.

On my system...

From: C:\app\PCNonAdmin\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc7.jar

To: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\ext\ojdbc7.jar

I hope this helps.