# Sonar Gradle Plugin: Package is sealed error

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

When running a gradle task

`gradle clean test jacocoTestReport sonarqube`

i get the following error:

```
10:35:16.649 INFO  - Install plugins
10:35:16.764 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
10:35:16.773 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbserver
:sonarqube FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> Unable to execute Sonar
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 9.945 secs
sealing violation: package oracle.jdbc is sealed
```

I assume it is because the JDBC driver gets loaded by another plugin beforehand during my build process but the documentation of the plugin is lacking an option to turn off the JDBC driver download and i cannot find an issue tracker for the plugin.

The stacktrace is

```
11:41:47.969 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
11:41:47.969 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
11:41:47.970 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
11:41:47.970 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
11:41:47.970 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
11:41:47.970 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unable to execute Sonar
11:41:47.970 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
11:41:47.971 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
11:41:47.972 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
11:41:47.972 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
11:41:47.972 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
11:41:47.972 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
11:41:47.972 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
11:41:47.973 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
11:41:47.973 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
11:41:47.973 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
11:41:47.973 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
11:41:47.973 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
11:41:47.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:306)
11:41:47.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
11:41:47.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
11:41:47.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
11:41:47.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
11:41:47.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
11:41:47.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
11:41:47.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
11:41:47.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
11:41:47.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
11:41:47.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
11:41:47.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
11:41:47.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
11:41:47.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
11:41:47.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
11:41:47.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
11:41:47.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
11:41:47.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:48)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
11:41:47.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
11:41:47.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:50)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
11:41:47.978 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 57 more
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:77)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
11:41:47.979 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
11:41:47.980 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
11:41:47.980 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
11:41:47.980 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
11:41:47.980 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:81)
11:41:47.980 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
11:41:47.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
11:41:47.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
11:41:47.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 71 more
11:41:47.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
11:41:47.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
11:41:47.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
11:41:47.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1098)
11:41:47.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:350)
11:41:47.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.initDatasource(DefaultDatabase.java:103)
11:41:47.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:72)
11:41:47.982 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 85 more
11:41:47.983 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package oracle.jdbc is sealed
11:41:47.983 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
11:41:47.983 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 90 more
11:41:47.983 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Comment: Have you tried running with `--stacktrace` and `--debug` as suggested in the error message?

Comment: Yes but the error persists of course and the information is not enlightening

Comment: What's your jvm version? What's your oracle driver version? Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922369/java-security-exception-sealing-violation-while-trying-to-connect-to-database) can help?

Comment: The local version is the same as in the sonar extensions folder. The problem is that the plugin wants to download the jdbc driver although it is already loaded in the classpath from previous operations in the gradle script and i dont see a way to prevent that

Comment: What if you run the analysis in a separate command?

Comment: The same error because the JDBC driver gets loaded by another script globally for gradle. But i found a workaround and installed a flag in the other plugin that prevents it from loading when not needed.