# sealing violation: package oracle.net.ns is sealed

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

I am trying to connect to an Oracle 11g XE databse using Oracle SQL Developer. However, I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package oracle.jdbc.driver is sealed
```

I have searched for an answer on the web, but have not found a solution.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: review this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922369/java-security-exception-sealing-violation-while-trying-to-connect-to-database

Answer (score 12):

From this documentation at Oracle : [Known Issues and Limitations](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-4728/6n6s25ei6/index.html) :

> **java.lang.SecurityException: Sealing violation exception (ID 6554602)**
>
> **Description**
>
> Starting with JDBC 10.2 drivers, having more than one JDBC
> jar file in the CLASSPATH may result in a java.lang.SecurityException:
> Sealing violation exception.
>
> **Solution**
> (Suggested by Oracle) Make sure that the CLASSPATH includes
> only one JDBC driver JAR file.

And this forum : [SecurityException: sealing violation  from  Class.forName](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1160757?start=0)

> A sealing violation means that some classes from a sealed package were
> loaded from two different locations (directories or jar files).
>
> A sealed package is one that essentially says "I know that all classes
> in this package come from a single jar file. For security reason no
> other location may provide classes that are in this package".
>
> Chances are you have two Oracle JDBC driver jars in your classpath.

So make sure that you don't have multiple Oracle JDBC driver jar libraries in your classpath.

Comment: C:\Users\aVinci>ECHO %CLASSPATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib;C:\Users\aVinci\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\aVinci\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;.

Comment: @VinciADePaul : check the jars contained in those different locations.

Answer (score 2):

It happens when you have more than one JDBC jar file in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: @berger                                                                                   THIS is my classpath, and there is no jar file:

C:\Users\aVinci>ECHO %CLASSPATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib;C:\Users\aVinci\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\aVinci\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;.

Comment: Make you sure Oracle SQL Developer classpath is not defined as -cp option on the command line that runs it. Furthermore, directories listed in the the CLASSPATH environment variable could contain jdbc driver.